# Sharing a video from android device to Whatsapp

Tags: java, android

I am using the following code for sharing a video from the android device to whatsapp:

```
public void shareVideoWhatsApp() throws IOException {
   File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
   String fileName = "test.mp4";
   File v = new File(SDCardRoot, fileName);
   // Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(v);
   Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",v);
   Intent videoshare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   videoshare.setType("video/*");
   videoshare.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
   videoshare.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
   videoshare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
   startActivity(videoshare);
}
```

My problem now is there are two types of whatsapp:

1. Normal whatsapp with the package code com.whatsapp
2. Whatsapp Business with the package code com.whatsapp.w4b

How do I implement the share feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As WhatsApp and WhatsApp for Business are two different apps, you cant send intents to both of them at the same time. What you can do is either

1. Let the user choose which WhatsApp App they want to send it to. I would recommend doing this as most users will have the same contacts on the for business app and the normal app.
2. Send to both of them at the same time. Simply start the activities on after the other